# Keep USB PD and USB hub alive when external display enters standby

Tags: laptop, external-display, standby, usb-c, lg-monitor

My Win10 laptop (Dell XPS 13 9350) is connected via USB-C to an LG display, where several USB devices including an HDD are attached (unfortunately only with USB 2.0 speed due to USB-C & Alternate Mode limitations).

I want the display to go black after some minutes, ideally power saving mode, without turning the USB Power Delivery or USB hub off, in case I render a video or compile code.

Currently, when the power settings tell the display to go into standby, the USB hub and PD feature also power off, not just the display, and the notebook runs out of battery and the potentially data on HDD gets corrupted, so I have to disable display standby in Windows 10 power settings.

I did not find any display settings to do so, but would imagine that lots of people face the same problem. Do third-party tools or drivers exist that might solve this problem? Is it only an LG specific problem?

Comment: Have you tried changing USB selective suspend setting? https://www.groovypost.com/howto/usb-selective-suspend-windows-explained/

Comment: @DrMoishePippik how should that be helpful, other than preventing standby at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your monitor settings. My LG monitor with USB-C connection has a "Deep Sleep Mode". If this is enabled and monitor enters standby the USB hub is also disabled.